# How to ignore first user input in Python 3

Tags: tips, python

I have 2 inputs: 1 single number and some numbers separated by whitespace:

```
1
1 2 3 4 5
```

I want to loop over the second input, and I don't need the first input. I did this, which works:

```python
input()
for x in input().split():somecode()
```

But can I go directly to the second input without doing the `input()` at the beginning or with shorter code?

I tried this code (-2 bytes) but it doesn't work, it needs two `input()` to work:

```python
a,b=input()
for x in b.split():somecode() #Error : not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

a,b=input(),input()
for x in b.split():somecode() #OK
```

Comment: If you're using `print` only once in the `somecode` section, it might be useful to assign `input` to a variable and use that to print the output as well. This saves one byte over the `open(0)` method, but has conditions to use it

Comment: Is this in Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @xnor 3, and thank you for editing

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## `open(0)`, 40 bytes

The builtin function [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#open) returns a file object which can be iterated over, line by line. Usually you pass a path to `open`, but it also takes *file descriptor*, which are integers that refer to special files.

`0` is the file descriptor for the standard input ([source](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html?highlight=file%20descriptor#file-descriptor-operations)), and this allows you to open the input as file with `open(0)`.

Converting this file to a list (of lines) and accessing the second entry saves 3 bytes in this case:

```python
for x in[*open(0)][1].split():somecode()
```

Other than `input()` this does not remove trailing newline characters (`\n`), but in this case `split` takes care of it. Another downside is that you can not combine `input()` and `open(0)`.
The same technique often helps when you need to read multiple lines of input, example:

```python
# a is the first line of input, b the seconds and r contains all remaining lines.
a,b,*r=open(0)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 42 bytes

You can use `open(0)` to read all the inputs in once and unpack them.

```python
_,a=open(0)
for i in a.split():somecode(i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/5fnJ@bmpyfkmpbUJSZV/I/XifRNr8gNU/DQJMrLb9IIVMhM08hUa@4ICezREPTCqZaI1Pz/3@3zKLiEq5goEBeikJIRmZRioJbfmlRSQYA)

if the inputs contains more than two lines you can also use:

```python
_,*a=open(0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P15HK9E2vyA1T8NA839BUWZeiUai5n@3zKLiEq7g1OT8vBSukIzMohQut/zSopIMAA)

but it will append a trailing newline to all the elements but the last